# Независимый блок

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Понимаю вопрос может быть не слишком понятен, но постараюсь изложить суть как можно яснее. 
Есть блоки в которых расположен контент, они имеют свойство `display: inline-block` и расположены горизонтально. Я хочу сделать один из элементов интерактивным (при клике на него он заменяется на другой элемент. 
Так вот если использовать `inline-block`, то при плавном изменении элемента (я делаю это путем `show`/`hide`) дергается и содержимое других. То есть я не могу просто изменить элемент, никак не затрагивая остальные. 
Думаю что нужно сделать элементы независимыми друг от друга. Но реализация страдает.

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб не было дергания, Вам нужно реализовывать сменяемые блоки внутри жестко позиционируемых блоков.

Варианты:

1. Абсолютно позиционирумый блок - в этом случае вне общего потока, потому дергания не будет.
2. Смена контента внутри жестко заданного блока - `div` или иного, с соответствующими параметрами в `css`
3. Жестко заданные ячейки в таблице.
4. Фоновая замена
5. `iframe`
6. В сопряженных слоях - то есть, рамка и прочее в одном слое, замена и все прочее - в другом.
   ...

*Как задать жесткие размеры - инфо в инете достаточно.